# ExtensionNotFound Error while all extensions are supported in go-vulkan

Tags: go, vulkan

While creating a Logical Device in go-vulkan an `ErrorExtensionNotPresent(-7)` error is occurring and I am not sure why. All the extensions are supported while enumerating the Physicaldeviceextensions.

Below is the actual code.

```
func (p *Engine) CreatePhysicalDevice() {
    var pPhysicalDeviceCount uint32
    result := vk.EnumeratePhysicalDevices(p.Instance, &pPhysicalDeviceCount, nil)
    if result != vk.Success {
        panic(result)
    }
    physicalDevices := make([]vk.PhysicalDevice, pPhysicalDeviceCount)
    result = vk.EnumeratePhysicalDevices(p.Instance, &pPhysicalDeviceCount, physicalDevices)
    if result != vk.Success {
        panic(result)
    }
    p.PhysicalDevice = physicalDevices[0]

    indices := p.findQueueFamily()
    var uniqueIndice []uint32
    uniqueIndice = append(uniqueIndice, *indices.graphicsFamily)
    if *indices.graphicsFamily != *indices.presentFamily {
        uniqueIndice = append(uniqueIndice, *indices.presentFamily)
    }
    var pPropertyCount uint32
    vk.EnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties(p.PhysicalDevice, "", &pPropertyCount, nil)
    deviceExtensions := []string{"VK_KHR_swapchain", "VK_KHR_display_swapchain"}

    propertyList := make([]vk.ExtensionProperties, pPropertyCount)
    vk.EnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties(p.PhysicalDevice, "", &pPropertyCount, propertyList)
    for _, property := range propertyList {
        property.Deref()
        extensionName := string(property.ExtensionName[:])
        nullIndex := bytes.IndexByte(property.ExtensionName[:], 0)
        if nullIndex != -1 {
            extensionName = extensionName[:nullIndex]
        }
        contains := false
        for _, ext := range deviceExtensions {
            if extensionName != ext {
                contains = true
            }
        }
        if !contains {
            panic("Extension Not found")
        }
        fmt.Println("Extension Physical:", extensionName)
    }
    queuePriority := float32(1.0)
    queueCreateInfos := []vk.DeviceQueueCreateInfo{}
    for _, index := range uniqueIndice {

        info := vk.DeviceQueueCreateInfo{
            SType:            vk.StructureTypeDeviceQueueCreateInfo,
            Flags:            vk.DeviceQueueCreateFlags(0),
            QueueFamilyIndex: index,
            QueueCount:       1,
            PQueuePriorities: []float32{queuePriority},
        }
        queueCreateInfos = append(queueCreateInfos, info)

    }
    var pdFeatures vk.PhysicalDeviceFeatures
    vk.GetPhysicalDeviceFeatures(p.PhysicalDevice, &pdFeatures)
    enabledLayer := []string{"VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation"}
    createInfo := vk.DeviceCreateInfo{
        SType:                   vk.StructureTypeDeviceCreateInfo,
        Flags:                   vk.DeviceCreateFlags(0),
        QueueCreateInfoCount:    uint32(len(queueCreateInfos)),
        PQueueCreateInfos:       queueCreateInfos,
        EnabledExtensionCount:   uint32(len(deviceExtensions)),
        PpEnabledExtensionNames: deviceExtensions,
        EnabledLayerCount:       uint32(len(enabledLayer)),
        PpEnabledLayerNames:     enabledLayer,
        PEnabledFeatures:        []vk.PhysicalDeviceFeatures{pdFeatures},
    }

    result = vk.CreateDevice(p.PhysicalDevice, &createInfo, nil, &p.LogicalDevice)
    if result != vk.Success {
        panic(result)
    }
}
```

I tried to see if it was because I was using XCB surface on a Wayland Arch system and If all the extension are supported by enumerating the physcialdeviceextensions.

As u can see in code error it is only occurring while in `CreateDevice`.